# Using Spectrify to offload data from Redshift to S3 in Parquet format

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parquet

I'm trying to use [Spectrify](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/spectrify/v1.0.1/spectrify.pdf) to unload data from Redshift to S3 in Parquet format, but I'm stuck in the process because I can't understand a few things. Spectrify documentation isn't great and I can't find any implementation example on the internet. I've also found a similar question here on StackOverflow, but the accepted answer is that it's recommended to use Spectrify which doesn't help much.

Here is the problem (this is the code from their documentation):

```
from spectrify.export import RedshiftDataExporter
from spectrify.convert import ConcurrentManifestConverter
from spectrify.utils.schema import SqlAlchemySchemaReader

RedshiftDataExporter(sa_engine, s3_config).export_to_csv('my_table')

csv_path_template = 's3://my-bucket/my-table/csv/{start.year}/{start.month:02d}/{start.day:02d}'
spectrum_path_template = 's3://my-bucket/my-table/spectrum/partition_key={start}'
csv_path = csv_path_template.format(start=start_date)
spectrum_path = spectrum_path_template.format(start=start_date)
s3_config = SimpleS3Config(csv_path, spectrum_path)

sa_table = SqlAlchemySchemaReader(engine).get_table_schema('my_table')
ConcurrentManifestConverter(sa_table, s3_config).convert_manifest()
```

`RedshiftDataExporter` is used to export data to CSV, `sa_engine` is a connection to Redshift engine.

Their documentation is vague on the conversion process. What would be the process here which should be used to unload data to CSV and then turn it into Parquet format while using Spectrify in a Python 3.x script? How should I modify the above code and what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now unload Redshift data to S3 in Parquet format without any third party application. The new feature is now supported in Redshift:

```
UNLOAD ('select-statement')
TO 's3://object-path/name-prefix'
FORMAT PARQUET
```

Documentation can be found at [UNLOAD - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html)

Comment: Well, unfortunately, it wasn't available when we needed it so we took the route of mimicking unload in JSON format and then converting it through EMR. But we will certainly use this in the future.